# This suspend function is taking very long time to execute ,How can I optimize this?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I am writing code to get the newsfeed from the database and to show this feed in UI. This is my Firestore database structure:

```
users->uniqueUserId |-->UsersProfileInfo--->Profile(document)
                    |-->FeedNewsFeed |--->unique documents for each newsfeed
                                     |--->unique documents for each newsfeed
                                     |--->unique documents for each newsfeed
```

to get each news feed from every user in my user collection I have to write nested for loops which takes some extra time and getting data from Firestore also takes some times, so is there any nice way to optimize this problem.

**Function for getting newsfeed**

```
 suspend fun getAllNewsFeeds(): ArrayList<NewsFeedClass> {

    list.clear()

    val querySnapshot = collectionRef.get().await()

    //Traversing through each document in collection
    for (document in querySnapshot) {

        val currDocRef = document.reference
        //Getting user name
        val userName =
                 currDocRef
                .collection(Constants.UserProfileInfo)
                .document(Constants.Profile)
                .get()
                .await()
                .toObject(FeedUserName::class.java)?.userName


       // adding username in newsFeedClass for displaying on newsfeed
        val newsFeedClass = NewsFeedClass()
        if (userName != null) {
            newsFeedClass.username = userName
        }
        //getting QuerySnapshot from FeedNewsFeed collection
        val newsFeedQuerySnapshot =
                 currDocRef
                .collection(Constants.FeedNewsFeeds).get().await()
        //Traversing through each document in 
        // collecting and respectively  adding feed on newsFeedClass
        //adding newsFeedClass to list 
        for (documentOfFeed in newsFeedQuerySnapshot) {

            val thisDocRef = documentOfFeed.reference

            val feed =
                thisDocRef
                .get().await().toObject<FeedNewsFeed>()

            if (feed != null) {
                newsFeedClass.content = feed.newsfeed
                list.add(NewsFeedClass(newsFeedClass.username, newsFeedClass.content))
            }
        }
    }
    list.shuffle()
    return list

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing in your code is the expected behavior. Why? Because at every iteration of your loop, you are reading data from Firestore using get() and right after that you call await(). This means that all the operations run one after another. It basically means, that at each iteration of your loop, you wait until you get the data from the database. The more iterations you have, the longer it will take. So these operations run sequentially, and not in parallel as you probably might think.

If you need to get the data in parallel you can add the [kotlinx-coroutines-play-services](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/tree/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services) library to your project and use the [asDeferred](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-play-services/kotlinx.coroutines.tasks/as-deferred.html) extension function that converts a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) into a [Deferred](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/-deferred/) object. In the end, you can call the [awaitAll()](https://kotlinlang.org/api/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/await-all.html) extension function that will wait while all Firestore read operations are loaded in **parallel**. So in code, it should look like this:

```
val tasks: MutableList<Deferred<DocumentSnapshot>> = mutableListOf()
for (document in querySnapshot) {
    val currDocRef = document.reference
    val deferredTask = currDocRef
            .collection(Constants.UserProfileInfo)
            .document(Constants.Profile)
            .get()
            .asDeferred()
    tasks.add(deferredTask)
}

tasks.awaitAll().forEach { document ->
    //Do what you need to do with your documents.
}
```

Comment: I still have to use `await()` to get information from profile Document and from  FeedNewsFeed, If you got some time can you please help me optimize my  code.

Comment: In that case, you have to add all operations to a list and wait for operations to complete. There is also another option that you have, which is to add all the data that you need to be returned into a single collection. In that way, there is no need to query the database twice, but just once, right?

Comment: If you consider at some point in time try using the Realtime Database, here is a useful [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-optimize-firebase-realtime-database-calls-to-improve-performance-cc63dad374d5).

Comment: Hey. Can I help you with other information?

Comment: I changed My Structure of database and used Yours suggested code above  which helped  my code to run quit efficiently.

Comment: I think this  way of writing function to get data is a newbies way, I have studied your articles on `Medium` where you have used sealed class(sealed Response class) and interfaces to work out similar problem , I was having hard time understanding them ,can I get reference to some similar  articles which will help me understand .

Comment: Other resources, maybe the repos that correspond to those articles. Almost each one of them has a repo. So might check that out too.