# How to upload multiple Images to Firebase Storage using Task function and get back the urls

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-platform, firebase-storage

I want to upload multiple files in Firesbase and get back the URL when the upload is complete. I tried in a for loop uploading each one through and getting back the URLs and adding to a ArrayList

```
 override suspend fun addProductImagesToFirebaseStorage(productImages: List<Uri>): AddProductImagesResponse {
    return try {

       val downloadUrls: MutableList<Uri> = arrayListOf()

        for (item in productImages){

            val productDownloadUrl =  categoryImageStorage.reference.child("HomeFeed").child("Products")
                .child("Product${UUID.randomUUID()}")
                .putFile(item).await()
                .storage.downloadUrl.await()
                downloadUrls.add(productDownloadUrl)

        }

        Success(downloadUrls)

    }catch (e:Exception){
        Failure(e)
    }
}
```

Is this is correct way to do it and want to know how to do it with [Task<>whenAllSuccess](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Tasks#whenAllSuccess(java.util.Collection%3C?%20extends%20com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task%3C?%3E%3E))

I tried using Task in this way please correct me with this method

```
 override suspend fun addTestProductImagesToFirebase(testImages: List<Uri>): AddProductImagesResponse {

    return try{
        val downloadUrls: MutableList<Uri> = arrayListOf()
        val taskArrayList: MutableList<Task<Uri>> = arrayListOf()
       val task = testImages.forEach {
            taskArrayList.add(
                categoryImageStorage.reference.child("HomeFeed").child("Products")
                    .child("Product${UUID.randomUUID()}")
                    .putFile(it).await()
                    .storage.downloadUrl
            )

        }

        Tasks.whenAll(taskArrayList).addOnSuccessListener {
            downloadUrls.add(it)
        }

        Success(downloadUrls)
    }catch (e:Exception){
        Failure(e)
    }

}
```

and want to know if uploading with the Tasks function is a more efficient way of doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're almost there. To understand it better, I recommend you split the operations. First, you have to create a list of UploadTask objects:

```
val tasks = mutableListOf<UploadTask>()
productImages.forEach {
    val task = categoryImageStorage.reference
                                   .child("HomeFeed")
                                   .child("Products")
                                   .child("Product${UUID.randomUUID()}")
                                   .putFile(it) // Creates the UploadTask object.
    tasks.add(task)
}
```

Once you have the list full of UploasTask objects, then pass it to `whenAllSuccess()` method like this:

```
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask>(tasks).addOnSuccessListener { uploadTasks ->
    val downloadUrls = mutableListOf<Uri>()
    uploadTasks.forEach {
        downloadUrls.add(it.await().storage.downloadUrl.await())
    }
    //Do what you need to do with the list.
}
```

Comment: I have a doubt should i add await( ) function inside another suspend function because studio is showing error the method is already a override suspend function

Comment: await() is a suspend function and such a function can only be called from another suspend function or from a coroutine.

Comment: while adding the uploadTasks for each to downloadUrls  this line => "it.await().storage.downloadUrl.await()" .await( ) alone is showing error : stating that "Suspension functions can be called only within coroutine body ". so only i had doubt need to call this with another suspend block

Comment: Or launch a coroutine.

Comment: there is Class Exception of " com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask"

Comment: Be sure to use the correct import.

Comment: I can only select one import: import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask

Comment: @Captai-N That's all you need in order to use a UploadTask.

Comment: @Alex Mamo But it dosen't work. Now i have build a workaround: Task.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>... uploadTask.forEach{it-> it.metadata!!.reference!!... But this is not the best solution i think